# Integral of $x e^{cx^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

How to evaluate the  indefinite integral
$\int x e^{cx^3}$. Is there any general form of solution for this integral?
some function in terms of hypergeometric function or similar kind of functions?
Here c is a positive constant

Comment: https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjVkZLT66fHAhVHB44KHaadBCw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGamma_function&ei=l3zNVZXqNceOuASmu5LgAg&usg=AFQjCNFs2uwOp4Ot2aOBPTAugme2fpYwZw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start changing variable $$c x^3=-t$$ $$x=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{t}}{\sqrt[3]{c}}$$ $$dx=-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{c}\, t^{2/3}}\,dt$$ All of that gives $$I=\int x e^{cx^3}\,dx=\frac{1}{3 c^{2/3}}\int t^{-1/3}{e^{-t}}\,dt$$ where you probably recognize the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Well my friend ... you beat me to it!  See, you've still got it ... whatever "it" is.

Comment: @Anu. This makes $t<0$. It is just a change of variable.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Now i got it. Thank you

Comment: @Anu. You are very welcome !

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

We have
$$\int xe^{cx^3}dx$$ Let $cx^3=t\implies 3cx^2dx=dt\iff dx=\frac{t^{-2/3}dt}{3\sqrt[3]{c}}$ $$\int \left(\frac{t}{c}\right)^{1/3}e^{t}\frac{t^{-2/3}dt}{3\sqrt[3]{c}}$$ $$=\int \frac{e^{t}t^{-1/3}dt}{3c^{2/3}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}\int t^{-1/3} e^{t}dt$$
I hope you can solve further.